# Converting a string to a range

Tags: vba, excel

I have read nearly every forum on the Internet and I cannot find a way to use a string as a Range Address. I found one answer on your forum that stated you could convert a Range to a String but not the other way round.

Example:

```
Dim str As String = "A1"
MsgBox Worksheets(1).Range(str)
```

My question is: 
Can I use a string in a Range object?

Comment: I tested your code and it worked as expected. So what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can on the condition that it is a valid index. 
In this very simple demonstrative example, I've used `debug.print` to print a `range.value` using a `str` as its index.

[image]

Comment: Thumb me up my friend!

Comment: The problem I was having related to the string. I was setting the string to a range of cells "A1:A10" and my call Msgbox   Range(str) could not work as the str was invalid. By adding Range(str).Cells(1,1) it worked.